# Help Ubuntu 16.04 - Slowest OS I've ever encountered!

Tags: 64-bit

Laptop - Panasonic Toughbook CF-C1
Processor I5
Harddrive - 256gb SSD
Ram - 4GB

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 onto this machine.  No matter what I do on this machine, it takes between 3 and 15 seconds to respond. When I click on a file or app it responds in about 10 seconds. Screens grey out and lock up. As I type my fingers are about 5 or six words ahead of the the cursor.

I've been using ubuntu for about 10 years.  This is the first time I've ever had this problem.  So far this is the worst OS I've ever used.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: post pertinent details. hardware specs etc.  As an interim solution, perhaps a different version of ubuntu will solve your issue.  Was this a clean install or upgrade? If you log in via the terminal, is the responsiveness equally slow?

Comment: It is a Panasonic Toughbook CF-C1, 2.4 Gzh i5, 4gb ram, Samsung 256gb SSD. Fresh install.  This machine is supposed to be ubuntu compatible.